# Italicize text containing a link

Tags: restructuredtext

I have an RST where I want an italicized link. However, the markup

```
*Warning: `Watch this <http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ob=av3e>`_!*
```

renders in HTML as

```
<em>Warning: `Watch this <http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ob=av3e>`_!</em>
```

That is, the italics render but the link doesn't. How do I get italics around the link?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that reST markup cannot be nested.

I managed to get it work with this:

```
Warning: |text|_

.. _text: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ob=av3e

.. |text| replace:: *Watch this*
```

Comment: Yikes. I've been using raw HTML as the workaround, and I think I'll stick to that. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Almost 10 years later, has nothing changed?

Comment: @AlexReinking: I'm not aware of anything, but I haven't used reST for a while now. The above works fine in Markdown.

Comment: That's kind of sad. Markdown is so fragmented, it's hard to have reliable tooling support (eg. paragraph reflow, formatters), but then reST lacks basic nesting while having great extensibility options.

Comment: Indeed, I dislike the fragmentation of Markdown. With Pandoc there is a large flavor, and with CommonMark we also have a specification. But not everything uses CommonMark. What do you use reST for?

Answer (score 0):

Another option in this case is to use [unicode italic text](https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=ITALIC):

```
: `  <http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ob=av3e>`_!
```

Although this does mean that you are stuck with the specific formatting of those unicode characters (you can get a serif version too).